# How create relation a user with many favorite things?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I need create favorite things of users, a user have many favorite things, my question is, which is the better way this relation?

my first idea is:

```
@Column(name = "favorite")
    Set<Favorite> favorite;
```

my second idea is:

```
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
Favorite favorites;
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context. Perhaps share a schema, how you plan on querying displaying this data. It's not just about how to store this field but you have to think if it makes sense for reading/writing and maintenance perspective.

Comment: @na-98 i not have a lot experence with programming, i want to know advantage for my two ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second idea is better.

Mapping to a new table Favourites will allow you to make your code/db design more readable in the sense that all attributes for the favorites are easily visible.

The first option doesn't really make sense as you'll be persisting this entire list as an attribute for each row -> this is too condensed.

Also, from the User class your mapping should be @OneToMany not @ManyToOne

Comment: And `Favorite favorite;` won't work; it needs to be a _collection_ of `Favorite`, such as a `Set<Favorite>` or a `List<Favorite>`.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction; you want a `Set<Favorite>` field, annotated with a `@OneToMany` mapping (or maybe a `@ManyToMany`, depending on how you want to represent favorites that are common to multiple users).